# file_get_contents in PHP to get a local asp file's render

Tags: php, asp-classic, windows-server-2003, file-get-contents

I have a running server in windows server 2003 hosting an ASP website. I have a PHP function trying to use `file_get_contents` from an URL that belongs to that server. The problem is both ASP URL and PHP functions belong the same server. I will explain it better:

My web www.myweb.com is hosted in my server.

The file www.myweb.com/phpfile.php needs to get the contents from the file www.myweb.com/aspfile.asp with `file_get_contents`. If I run `phpfile.php` from an external server it works, but if I run it from my server it fails.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that both files belong to same local host, so when I try to get `aspfile.asp` content it skips the web server and doesn't get the rendered content. 
My question is: How can I solve it? How can I exactly tell the server to look for the rendered content instead looking in local host?

Comment: Try doing it with a relative path instead of the whole thing including the domain. Also, please show your code and the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch a HTTP URL from your server. Otherwise, when accessing the ASP file directly, you will not trigger the ASP rendering because you will read the actual source code from the file.

Whether or not your server is setup to accept connections to itself is to be checked. Usually this is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I got that. But how? I use the whole url with the domain: file_get_contents('https:\\www.myweb.com/aspfile.asp'). How do I have to send the request?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the following on my dev server and it seems to work

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://localhost/mydirectory/myaspfile.asp';
$string = file_get_contents($url);
print $string
?>
```

My php and asp files are in the same directory.  Is it possible that you have a firewall which is preventing your php installation from making outgoing connections?

If anyone's interested, here's how to do the same thing in asp.

```
<% 
url = "http://localhost/mydirectory/myaspfile.asp" 
set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "" 
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the interest. I kind of solved it. The question is it's not my server, but my customer's. Maybe it was any issue with the firewall or router, or maybe it worked when I added the local ip of the server to the hosts file..